# Powershell calling one function from another

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of learning Powershell and have hit a situation where I cannot seem to call one function from another?

My test script has the following code:

```
Import-Module PSStdLib -Verbose -Force
plSetLevel 12
```

The imported module has the following code:

```
function plFileAppend { 
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS

        .DESCRIPTION

        .PARAMETER FileName
        FileName

        .PARAMETER Output
        Output

        .PARAMETER Variables
        Variables


        .EXAMPLE

    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Default", Position=1)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Variable", Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [String]$FileName, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Default", Position=2)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Variable", Position=2)]
    [String]$Output, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Variable", Position=3)]
    [String[]]$Variables 

    )

    # Scan the output for variable markers.
    $lVarsInOutput = ($Output.ToCharArray() | Where-Object {$_ -eq '{'} | Measure-Object).Count

    # No variable substitutions.
    if ($lVarsInOutput -eq 0 ) {
        $Output | Out-File $FileName -Append
    } else {
    # Variables passsed to substitute into output.
        $lVaiablesOut = $Variables[ 0..($lVarsInOutput-1) ]
        $Output -f  $lVaiablesOut | Out-File $FileName -Append
    }
}
```

and after the definition of the above function ....

```
function plSetLevel { 
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS

        .DESCRIPTION


        .PARAMETER Output
        Step


        .EXAMPLE

    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateRange(1,9999)]
    [int]$Step 

    )

    if ( plIfExists($psRestartFile) ) { Remove-Item $psRestartFile }
    plFileAppend $psRestartFile "STAMP=$psExecStamp"
    plFileAppand $psRestartFile "PID=$psPID"
    plFileAppand $psRestartFile "STEP=$Step"

}
```

When I attempt to run the plSetLevel function I get the following:

```
plFileAppand : The term 'plFileAppand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At S:\PS\Home\Library\PSStdLib\PSStdLib.psm1:1093 char:5
+     plFileAppand $psRestartFile "PID=$psPID"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (plFileAppand:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

plFileAppand : The term 'plFileAppand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At S:\PS\Home\Library\PSStdLib\PSStdLib.psm1:1094 char:5
+     plFileAppand $psRestartFile "STEP=$Step"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (plFileAppand:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have imported the module with Verbose and Force and the output seems like things are loading in the correct order?

```
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'S:\PS\Home\Library\PSStdLib\PSStdLib.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'plDebugPrint'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'plFileAppend'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'plGetKeyValue'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'plGetKeyValues'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'plIfExists'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'plOSInfo'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'plSetLevel'.
```

Everything I have found by Google seems to address the situation where the definition of the called function has to be before the calling function.  That does not seem to be the case here.  What am I missing?  Can Powershell not call one function from another?
I suspect it is a scope issue?  Is there a way that I can resolve this issue and still have the code in functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no issue - you are calling a function you *haven't* defined.

In the module you define the function by the name of

```
plFileAppend
```

but you call a function by the name of

```
plFileAppand
```

ie. the last **e** has been replaced by an **a**

Comment: Dog gone.  I knew it was something simple, but sheesh.  Not enough coffee yet today

Comment: Happens even to the best of us ;-)